# Sewing machine speed and needle position control over arduino

Tags: arduino, resistors, sensor, motor-controller

I need control sewing machine speed and needle position over arduino project.

- Current sewing machine is: Brother X5, with 70 Watt motor with foot pedal control.

Speed of motor will controlling by triac dimmer (image attached) but want to change dimmer resistance (rheostat) throw arduino, progragrammatically. Not with servo motor.
[image]

Q1: How can I change resistor resistance to form arduino programmatically?

Q2: Can I control motor speed sending 220V AC as pulses? (without triac dimmer)

For needle position plan to use magnet sensor. "Reed Switch Magnetic Sensor" Or "Hall Sensor"
Problem is vibration of machine and spinning speed is factors,

Q3: Which sensor best suit in this case?

Comment: Q2: The most common type of AC motor, an induction motor, cannot be controlled this way since voltage and frequency affects speed (not only does the 220AC from the wall affect how fast it turns, but so does the 50/60Hz.). To control its speed you have to basically make a custom sine-wave which is very, very involved. You cannot speed control induction motors like a DC brushed motors. But I don't know what type of motor is used in a sewing machine.

Comment: Sewing machines are traditionally brushed motors offering speed control right down to 0. That kind of speed control is probably rather dangerous to hack : it probably isn't isolated from mains. The Arduino won't like that...

Comment: @DKNguyen home-grade sewing machines use brushed universal motors, not induction motors (as industrials may use) and triac control is indeed the successor to the original rheostats.  Fancier ones probably have servoed brushless motors.

Comment: There's really no easy, safe way to do triac control from an Arduino.  A finished appliance would possibly float the MCU at mains voltage (while isolating it from the user) but that grossly complicates debugging and is just plain not acceptable for a hobby project.  Otherwise you need an opto-coupler on the zero crossing detector, and probably an opto-triac to drive the power triac.  And of course an isolated supply to power the MCU.  In terms of realistic advice, the extreme degree of interaction with the mains means you should drop this project and pick something else to work on instead.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks you for detailed comment. In worst case I will use triac dimmer with manual rheostat,it means fixed motor speed, but needle position will controled. Like this project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFy6KSMqnZM&t=576
But I wanna project like this (without Embroidery) but speed controlled by programmatically.  What is your opinion about use PWM instead of triac dimmer?

Comment: Using comparable voltage DC is even more hazardous than AC.  This is just not a good project, and it's not going to work single speed because you can't position the needle at a speed you can sew at.

Comment: @jsotola - contrary to your false assumption, I (and presumably the other commenters as well) know and specifically responded to exactly what the asker needs, the ability to stop the needle up, or down. No one who has used a sewing machine would have been the least bit confused about that! The asker probably won't be able to both sew and do that at a single speed, especially on cheaper home machines that rely on flywheel inertia compensate for weak motors. Machines that can be set to stop up or down do the final vertical positioning more slowly than sewing speed.

Comment: @jsotola may be I can't explain clearly, sorry for my broken english. But Chris Stratton understand me 100% percent ) One of main think is I need - control speed of sewing and stop needle every time in down position. But after understanding all processes, I think this is out of my capacity. One of main problem, as you said, will inertia, which is calculating almost imposible.But peufeu 's advice in his practice, I think most fit my plan. - use "PWM like 10-20 kHz through a MOSFET". I hope, this PWM will provide smooth low speed and stable torque. I'm thinking on this case.

Comment: @vugar_saleh, your english is just fine .... i am the one that is the problem ... i was visualizing what you are trying to do and i imagined the wrong thing from the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the machine has a brushed or universal motor, you can use a triac dimmer to control its speed.

However, triac dimmers are annoying to control. They fire on each mains cycle, ie every 10ms on 50Hz mains which inserts a large phase lag in the control loop. Also the input-output curve is very nonlinear.

If you want to control needle position you will need fast and accurate control, so you don't want to insert a large phase lag in your control loop. You'd need a smart control algorithm to compensate for this lag.

A much better scheme is to rectify mains and smooth it with a capacitor, then use high-ish frequency PWM like 10-20 kHz through a MOSFET. This has much lower phase lag, and would be easier to control. You can also control current through the motor, if you want to control torque.

For example, I have several electric drills. Most drills use triac dimmers. When using such a drill to drive a screw it is impossible to control torque and speed accurately, and the screw always ends up either deep into the workpiece, or sticking out. Triac dimmers just aren't accurate. I have another mains powered drill which uses a rectifier and PWM dimmer, and this one is very easy to control, the screw ends up perfectly flush with the workpiece every time.

Note your project uses high voltage thus it will be dangerous. Be careful.

Comment: About "PWM like 10-20 kHz through a MOSFET" bit more question. As I know this only possible on DC. Can I use PWM for 220V AC?  
As @chris-stratton said, domestic sewing machine motor is universal motor, and this mean it will work with DC aslo, but how many volt DC I need?

About tagin needle position, in youtube some peaple use proximity sensor and it work fine.This project in low RPM, and for me also this kind of RPM is ok.
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFy6KSMqnZM&t=576

I also need like this video (without Embroidery) but motor speed controlled throug Arduino.

Comment: The guy in this video uses a triac dimmer to set motor speed, and a static relay to turn the motor on/off. This will work at slow rpm.